# Angular2 - Sharing Boolean Reference between two [(ngModel)] bindings

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm working on a wysiwyg type of form creator. I'm trying to make rows editable by selecting the row to edit and listing the keys from the object in a different component.

**Component A.ts**

```
onedit() {
  this.service.emit(this.rowConfig)
}
```

**Component B.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.subscribe({
    next: config => {
      this.data = config
      this.props = Object
          .keys(config)
          .reduce(/* convert to { key, inputType } */)
  })
}
```

**Component B.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let prop of props">
  <label>{{prop.key}}</label>
  <input [type]="prop.inputType" [(ngModel)]="data[prop.key]" />
</div>
```

This works for a couple input types that I've tried (text, number) but it isn't working for "checkbox". I even added an `ID` to the props entity and added the `id` and `name` attributes to the `<input [type]="prop.inputType" [id]="prop.ID" [name]="prop.ID" [(ngModel)]="data[prop.key]" />`

Is the reference for the boolean getting lost somewhere? Why isn't the two way bind working for checkboxes when the reference to the object is shared (it works for strings and numbers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here only issue is `[type]="prop.inputType"` , coz of dynamic input type checkbox is not working

I have found the way solution for that :

```
<input *ngIf='prop.inputType !== "checkbox"' [type]="prop.inputType" [name]='prop.name' [(ngModel)]="data[prop.key]" />

<input *ngIf='prop.inputType === "checkbox"' type='checkbox' [name]='prop.name' [(ngModel)]="data[prop.key]" />
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-input-types)**

Comment: Is this a bug in angular?